# BarCodeScanning Not Working Swift iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, barcode-scanner, avcapturesession

Before you jump and tell me its a duplicate or send me links check out the code.

The camera shows up but the delegate for output is not called.

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

protocol ScannerViewControllerOutputDelegate : class {
    func scannerOutput(scannedString: String?)
}

class ScannerViewController: UIViewController {

    public weak var delegate: ScannerViewControllerOutputDelegate?

    @IBOutlet private weak var cameraView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet private weak var lblDataType: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var lblDataInfo: UILabel!

    private let captureSession: AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    private var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

    private var presenter: ScannerViewPresenter?

    deinit {
        captureSession.stopRunning()
        presenter = nil
        delegate = nil
    }

    @IBAction func didTapCancelButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("ScannerViewController -> USER CANCLED: will hide scannerview controller")
        captureSession.stopRunning()
        dismiss(animated: true) {
            print("ScannerViewController -> USER CANCLED: did hide scannerview controller")
            self.delegate?.scannerOutput(scannedString: nil)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        presenter = ScannerViewPresenter(withController: self)

        self.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        view.backgroundColor = .eify_darkGray

        guard let videoInput = initializeDeviceCamera() else {
            presenter?.deviceNotSupportedAlert()
            return
        }

        guard captureSession.add(captureInput: videoInput) else {
            presenter?.deviceNotSupportedAlert()
            return
        }

        guard captureSession.addMetadataOutput(withDelegate: self, andQueue: .global()) else {
            presenter?.deviceNotSupportedAlert()
            return
        }

        setupScanPreview()
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }

    fileprivate func initializeDeviceCamera() -> AVCaptureDeviceInput? {
        guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) else {
            presenter?.deviceNotSupportedAlert()
            return nil
        }
        do {
            let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput
            videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
            return videoInput
        } catch let outError as NSError {
            presenter?.deviceNotSupportedAlert()
            print("ScannerViewController -> Device Not Supported: \(outError.description)")
            return nil
        }
    }

    fileprivate func setupScanPreview() {
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = cameraView.layer.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    }

    fileprivate func stopSession() {
        if (captureSession.isRunning == true) {
            captureSession.stopRunning()
        }
    }

    fileprivate func startSession() {
        if (captureSession.isRunning == false) {
            captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        startSession()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        stopSession()
    }

    fileprivate func found(code: String?) {
        delegate?.scannerOutput(scannedString: code)
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .all
    }
}

extension ScannerViewController : AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        captureSession.stopRunning()
        if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
            let readableObject = metadataObject as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
            found(code: readableObject.stringValue)
        }
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}

extension AVCaptureSession {

    func add(captureInput videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput) -> Bool {
        if self.canAddInput(videoInput) {
            self.addInput(videoInput)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    func addMetadataOutput(withDelegate delegate: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate, andQueue queue: DispatchQueue) -> Bool {
        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        if self.canAddOutput(metadataOutput) {
            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(delegate, queue: queue)
            if metadataOutput.canAddObject(ofType: .qr) {
                metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]
            }
            self.addOutput(metadataOutput)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the delegate to `self`?

Comment: viewdidload ... captureSession.addMetadataOutput(withDelegate: self, ...

Comment: try setting a break point and see if the guard statement is executing successfully or is it going into the else block

Comment: Have you set breakpoints to confirm that the conditional code inside `addMetaDataOutput` is executing?

Comment: yep... its all exciting correctly. Just won't scan and give any output... its killing me

Comment: You have to import `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` delegate directly for `ViewController`. Not for extension.

Comment: Did that as well, did not make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the link @KiritModi how is the code in that link different to the one above? Rather, what am I missing that makes my code erroneous?

Comment: I don't compare the code but it's working in iOS 11. So I provide the link. the link have demo code . first you download and check it working. after you implement.